# Error while uploading app through application loader

Tags: iphone, ios

When we try to upload our latest application in (APP.zip) into the application loader, we get following error.

```
Apple's web service operation was not succeccful
Unable to authenticate the package: AppId.itmsp
ERROR ITMS-7002: "Caught exception validating "MZItmspRootPackage.validateLanguageCodeExists"" at (MZItmspRootPackage)
```

We created a distribution certificate with push notifications enabled. This may cause the bug, we have searched a lot and didn't find a proper way to solve this. What could we cause this error and how can we avoid it?

Comment: Xcode Version, Application Loader Version?

Answer (score 1):

you should do it from xcode directly, leave the application loader - it is not as good as xcode

here is how to do it:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your O/S, and upgrade your Xcode. It is pretty much impossible to develop for iPhone on a less-than-latest version of Mac OS.